# Which design pattern am I using?

Tags: design-patterns

I am developing a game. Instead of creating a class for each game entity I created an entity class and a feature class. Entity objects keep location, name, id and a list of entity features. I have bunch of feature classes derived from feature like movefeature, fuelfeature, displayfeature... If I need a moving entity I add movefeature to it. If it is a vehicle and burns fuel, it gets fuelfeature. Entities shown on screen have displayfeature and so on.

This probably is a design pattern and someone invented it before me. My question: is this method a valid pattern and what it is called?

Comment: this is probably just a general object-oriented design decision, not concrete pattern. You can have `IMoveFeature` interface and have several implementation of that Feature, like `FastMoving` or `RandomMoving`, which would allow you to substitute different features at runtime all sharing single interface or protocol, call it as you like. This would be a [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is really just [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) and favoring [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which is usually a good idea.

As for patterns, I'd say you prolly use a lot of them, conceptually at least if not strictly correct implementation-wise. Take a look at the [patterns listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) and you'll be able to indentify a bunch yourself just by the name and short description. By what you say I'd guess you might be using the following:

- Decorator, Strategy, Composite - to enable composition of complex entities from standalone parts and features,
- Factory, Builder - to automate creation of such complex entities,
- State, Observer, Mediator, Visitor, eventing, messaging - to enable entities and environment interactions,
- Module - to organize all this code,
- Singleton - as codebases just tend to have some every so often,
- and probably something for concurrency

See, patterns are like vegetarian thali, you just end up with mix and match of some, aware of em or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be more than one pattern depending on how you design/implement them.
I can see some of these possible patterns in there:

- [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

[image]

- [Chain of Responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

[image]

- [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

[image]